# Is Home Sale Legal Protection worth buying?

Tags: united-states, insurance, texas, house-sale

I'm selling my home and curious if "Home Sale Legal Protection" plans are worth purchasing. They are self described as covering the cost of lawyers for legal disputes about the information disclosed on a seller's disclosure (From "Seller's Shield"). It seems a little frivolous but it got me curious about the likelihood that I would be sued by the purchaser of my home. The best value plan seems to be $250 to cover up to $20,000 of legal fees in the event that I am sued in the 2 years after selling the home.

Of course we can assume they have to be making money off of this, so probably less than 1.25% of seller's experience a claimable event that pays out $20,000.

But I've just never heard of such a thing before and I don't know if it's worth it. My hunch is no but I don't have much information here.

Comment: What's your country and state (if in the USA)? That may affect the answer. Disclosure laws (and liabilities) change by state.

Comment: Are you worried about making an accurate disclosure?

Comment: I'm in Texas and I'm not *too* worried about my ability to give an accurate disclosure. But I'm not certain the next owner won't find something I did not know about and attempt to litigate.